# Click on element under div

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a radio button located under an hidden pop-up box.

The problem is, selenium keeps clicking on the hidden pop-up box instead of the radio button and throws an error.

How to make it click on the radio button instead of the hidden pop-up ?

Pop-up

```
<div style="z-index: 1008; opacity: 0.75; display: none;" id="a-popover-lgtbox"
class="a-declarative" data-action="a-popover-floating-close"></div>
```

Radio button

```
<input name="Rights-radio" value="PUBLIC_DOMAIN" type="radio"></input>
```

Python

```
rights_btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='PUBLIC_DOMAIN']")
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(rights_btn).click(rights_btn).perform()
```

Error

```
WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (237.0833282470703, 346.5). 
Other element would receive the click: <div style="z-index: 1008; opacity: 0; display: block; 
transition: all 250ms linear 0s;" id="a-popover-lgtbox" class="a-declarative" 
data-action="a-popover-floating-close"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element.SendKeys(Keys.Escape);
```

will close the popup, then you can click.