# Xpath in Selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium, xpath

I want to write `xpath` for the below flow :

1. Go to au.support.tomtom.com
2. click on Flag sign in the footer.
3. select Australia as a country

So far I have tried:

```
driver.get("http://au.support.tomtom.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rn_PageFooter_16']/footer/div[3]/button")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='//au.support.tomtom.com/app/answers/list/locale/en_AU']//[@text()='Australia']")).click();
```

Last `xpath` is not working.
I am using selenium JavaScript. Please help.

Comment: please write the html source in your question from the beginning <ul> and till the close </ul>

Comment: <ul>
<li>
<a style="text-transform: capitalize;" href="http://au.support.tomtom.com/app/results/locale/en_AU/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ2MDUzNzc1MC9zaWQvM25CQ2FWTm0%3D">
<span class="tt-flag-image australia"></span>
...
</a>
</li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>

Comment: xpath(//div[@class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6']/li[1]/a).click();

Comment: It is not working. 'driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6']/li[1]/a")).click();' 
**Error** : _Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6']/li[1]/a"}_
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: check if its under iframe

Comment: **Code So Far **
public class Locales_Australia 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {

  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  //maximize the screen
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  //give wait time
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  //get URL
  driver.get("http://au.support.tomtom.com/");
  //Click on Footer
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rn_PageFooter_16']/footer/div[3]/button")).click();
  //Click on Australia
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6']/li[1]/a")).click();
 }
}

Comment: No it is not under iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was your xpath which was causing the problem also your element was not on the view to be clickable

This below code is tested and worked for me

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class test1 {

@Test
public void chec() throws InterruptedException{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://Temp//imp//chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
    d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    d.get("http://au.support.tomtom.com/");
    d.manage().window().maximize();
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)d; 
    d.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rn_PageFooter_16']/footer/div[3]/button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    jse.executeScript("scroll(0, -250);");
    d.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/footer/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();


}
}
```

Comment: `{WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://au.support.tomtom.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rn_PageFooter_16']/footer/div[3]/button")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, -250);");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/footer/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
}`

Comment: Item is not clickable

Comment: You are right, since item is not visible on page, that's why it is not clicking that. I tried other countries that are on the footer and visible . Above code is working for that. Thanks. But how to work when item is not visible on page. Is there any function that can help me.

Comment: This was the error : - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (496.45001220703125, 145.3000030517578). Other element would receive the click: <a href="https://en.discussions.tomtom.com/" class="tt-nav-category-item tt-resize" data-text="Forum"></a>
Command duration or timeout: 77 milliseconds

Comment: use scroll accordingly to make it work :) it is a problem with your firefox versions i think please check with the compatible versions mark the answer as solved please thanks :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Why use XPath? It's much easier to find the Australia flag using CSS selector:

```
li .tt-flag-image.australia
```

Full code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li .tt-flag-image.australia")).click();
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (454.45001220703125, 144.03334045410156). Other element would receive the click: <a href="http://au.support.tomtom.com/app/manual?filter=manuals&amp;session=L3RpbWUvMTQ2MDU0NDY4Mi9zaWQvQ3F4SEJWTm0%3D" class="tt-nav-category-item tt-resize tt-pid " data-text="User Manuals"></a>
Command duration or timeout: 100 milliseconds <br>

Same error</br>

Comment: Your exception is a know issue with some browsers. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499095/click-on-element-under-div